# Can't access to lite-server in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

http://localhost:4200 doesn't work on host

But server is running inside container

```
docker exec 697bf01cf064 curl http://0.0.0.0:4200/


<!doctype html>
...
```

This command

```
docker-machine ip default
```

returns

```
192.168.99.100
```

http://192.168.99.100:4200 doesn't work too

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
697bf01cf064        wepoll_wepoll-ui-webpack-docker   "npm start --host=..."   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49152->49152/tcp   wepoll-ui-webpack-docker
```

EXPOSE 4200 49152 in Dockerfile

```
networks:
  dev-network:
  driver: bridge
```

Network driver - bridge

How to access container server from host? Firewall disabled.

docker inpect 68e5e3524906

```
[
    {
        "Id": "68e5e3524906d621f3abc3cdfcb58e740290bb12a2082e44c14e180fecabb111",
        "Created": "2017-02-01T16:56:34.52365653Z",
        "Path": "npm",
        "Args": [
            "start",
            "--host=0.0.0.0"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 4483,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-02-01T16:56:34.833112923Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:a8aa417d60182b300836ce3f556bf90ae5b71fcf1ef9f76f4ef0d41b461934d1",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/68e5e3524906d621f3abc3cdfcb58e740290bb12a2082e44c14e180fecabb111/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/68e5e3524906d621f3abc3cdfcb58e740290bb12a2082e44c14e180fecabb111/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/68e5e3524906d621f3abc3cdfcb58e740290bb12a2082e44c14e180fecabb111/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/68e5e3524906d621f3abc3cdfcb58e740290bb12a2082e44c14e180fecabb111/68e5e3524906d621f3abc3cdfcb58e740290bb12a2082e44c14e180fecabb111-json.log",
        "Name": "/wepoll-ui-webpack-docker",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "wepoll_dev-network",
            "PortBindings": {
                "4200/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "4200"
                    }
                ],
                "49152/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "49152"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "68e5e3524906",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "app",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "4200/tcp": {},
                "49152/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info",
                "NODE_VERSION=6.6.0",
                "HOME=/home/app",
                "APP_NAME=wepoll-ui-webpack-docker"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "npm",
                "start",
                "--host=0.0.0.0"
            ],
            "Image": "wepoll_wepoll-ui-webpack-docker",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/home/app/wepoll-ui-webpack-docker",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "b1e41fe8d248646d782943b8997d539b910c984b9a862335c080458afd44bd1e",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "wepoll",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "wepoll-ui-webpack-docker",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.10.0"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "7b8e3391317a645ec316183e6d1f8a4865418185598d8088d47f808987006bbf",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "4200/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "4200"
                    }
                ],
                "49152/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "49152"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7b8e3391317a",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "wepoll_dev-network": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "wepoll-ui-webpack-docker",
                        "68e5e3524906"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "4c5594b896a4050f60133f44e494021aaf5606488d22af963561febb0ee6049b",
                    "EndpointID": "603c3628945054bd62a9deaa574a782241b544502bb525333f2865da3f705d9a",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Is your host OS OSX?

Comment: @NehalJWani, my host OS - ubuntu 16.10

Comment: What's the output for `docker inspect docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' wepoll-ui-webpack-docker`

Comment: @NehalJWani, empty.
I have added all inspect output

Comment: When you visit: http://172.19.0.2:4200 in browser, what do you see?

Comment: @mkasberg You can see `0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49152->49152/tcp` in the output for `docker ps`

Comment: you need to expose 4200 port

Comment: @NehalJWani, This site can’t be reached

172.19.0.2 took too long to respond.

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk Is your app listening on `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: @NehalJWani, command: "npm start --host=0.0.0.0"

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk Inside container: `netstat -tnlp | grep 4200` or `lsof -i:4200` (you may have to install some packages to get these utilites)

Comment: @NehalJWani, thank you! It was running on localhost! 

** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200

Comment: i have changed command to ng serve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging:

The fact that you are unable to browse app at `${host_ip}:4200` means that it could be possible that the port is not exposed properly.

But the output for `docker ps` under the `PORTS` section has...

```
0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp
```

...which means that port has been exposed correctly.

Let's check if the port over the container's IP is reachable (to remove any suspicions on firewalls)

The output for `docker inspect ${container_id}` shows that your container IP is `172.19.0.2` (and also proves that the port bindings are correct). But http://172.19.0.2:4200 is also not reachable.

But you already mentioned that `curl 0.0.0.0` inside machine works, but 0.0.0.0, in this context, means "all IP addresses on the local machine" (in fact probably, "all IPv4 addresses on the local machine"), which also includes `127.0.0.1` aka `localhost`, which doesn't prove that your app is listening on all interfaces.

Now you say that you started the app with `--host=0.0.0.0`, but I think you can still override it inside the app code.

So, the best case scenario is to inspect how the app server is started.